# The "Reasonable User" theory of duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I think one of the problems that users, particularly newer ones, have with duplicate questions on our site is that we often don't seem to be closing questions as duplicates based on them being duplicates. At least, not in the way that word is normally used.

So I want to present what I feel is a theory that more accurately explains how duplicate closure gets used in practice: the Reasonable User theory of duplicate questions.

A user has a problem P. The user thus asks a question about how to solve P. There is a question which solves a problem Q, which does not appear to be P.

Let us say that problem P can be broken down into three sub-problems: A, Q, and B. The Reasonable User theory states that question P can be closed as a duplicate of question Q if:

1. Breaking problem P into sub-problems A, Q, and B is a trivial exercise for a "reasonable user". That is, a user searching for a solution to P either already knows about A, Q, and B, or is capable of recognizing that Q relates to their problem P.
2. Problems A and B are both trivially solvable for a "reasonable user". These would be basic things like "I need to loop over this set of items" or whatever.

I feel that a lot of questions get dupe-closed under the Reasonable User theory.  Indeed, most canonical questions are like this: they cover the core kernel of the issue, and the user is expected to apply its wisdom to their specific scenarios.

So my questions are these:

1. Is this a good theory for the reasons some questions get closed as duplicates?
2. Is it helpful to the site to close questions under this reasoning? My feeling is "yes", but it's useful to see arguments both for and against it.
3. If your answer to #2 was "yes", what can be done to make it more clear to people that "exact duplicate" can refer to cases like these?
4. When closing duplicates under this reasoning, is it useful to help explain to the OP how their question relates to the duplicate question? After all, they wouldn't have asked the question if they were a "Reasonable User" under this theory.

Comment: Those dupe closures are often solving a XY-problem IMHO. And yes, I am also sometimes leaving a comment to point this out.

Comment: A lot of people just don't like the idea of their question being closed at all.  I've seen people complain when their question is closed as a duplicate, only to be *super* grateful of someone posting an answer with *exactly* the same in formation in the duplicate to their question.  They (often correctly) assume that their question being considered a duplicate means they did something wrong, so they get defensive and do everything they can to fight it, rather than trying to figure out how to solve their problem using the answers on the duplicate.

Comment: @Servy even worse: they start complaning 2 min after the closure whereas you need at least 30min to carefully read the duplicate, understand it, test the solution, etc.

Comment: You say "reasonable user". I say "professional or enthusiastic".

Comment: Related: There's also the super-question (rather than sub-question) scenario. When a user would have no way in hell to know their question is sub-question of something else that's already answered, but gets their question closed as a "duplicate" anyway. Like it happened with my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55526389/541686)...

Comment: @Mehrdad In my experience, questions closed as duplicates are almost never duplicates of the questions linked to. Had I asked this question, the supposed duplicates would be of no help whatsoever. I understand your question, but not knowing much about HTML, the supposed duplicates are double Dutch to me. Basically, SO is saying "Sod off. Our desire to create some kind of encyclopedia for future googlers is far more important than helping you."

Comment: I honestly don't see the point of closing a question as a duplicate. This isn't a wiki and Google is the main way of finding answers. On the downside, having a question marked as a duplicate frustates users - especially when the old question really isn't a duplicate. Remove the feature.

Comment: @HansKilian: I see a usefulness in *identifying* duplicates, but I think I agree it shouldn't necessarily result in closure. The identification is helpful but the closure is a huge slap in the face, as if you shouldn't have asked it in the first place.

Comment: @Mehrdad as a side note, I am the one who closed your question and I am also the one who commmented in order to identify your issue and that issue is clearly explained in all the duplicates I have added. I see no point in adding an answer where I know the answer is somewhere else. If you claim this is not a duplicate when it's a clear one, I have nothing to add ...

Comment: @MatthewTaylor `In my experience, questions closed as duplicates are almost never duplicates of the questions linked to` --> question can be reopened if the duplicate is not a duplicate and you can edit your question to add more details to proove that the duplicate isn't helpful. Closing a question as duplicate is one way to answer the question and doesn't mean *why are you asking such question?? I will close it!*

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I claim it's not a duplicate question when it's clearly not a duplicate question. The *answer* may be a partial duplicate...

Comment: @Mehrdad `The answer may be a partial duplicate..` : then it's a duplicate. In your question you are having issue with quirks mode. Reading the duplicate will make you understand this and you will know that the missing  `doctype` is creating the weird behavior. We expect user to do some effort to actually read the duplcate, follow the links, check related question, etc ... don't expect answers like *hey mehrdad, you issue is the line 4 of your code because ...* but to get answers like *your issue is related to quirks mode* then you should do the search effort to understand quirks mode.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Why are you insinuating I didn't read the duplicate and didn't put effort into following the links etc.? I read it and understood it perfectly well, and I'm telling you the question is not a duplicate but the two questions have a common solution. That you're trying to pick another fight and resorting to attacking my competence and understanding of the matter just to force me to side with you a month after the whole thing was over should tell you something about the strength of your position. I'm not interested in continuing to argue with you.

Comment: @Mehrdad I am not insinuating *you* didn't read. I am talking in general. I have nothing against you and it's not about *you* or *me*. It's about question/answer. I am explaining that a duplicate question is a question that will give the path to the user in order to understand his issue and he need to follow this path. I don't care what the user will do later and how he will behave and if he read the duplicate or not but if someone claim it's not a duplicate I have to argue since I am the one who closed it and I will argue based on the question/answer not on the user behavior or competence.

Comment: To be fair the description for `close as duplicate` reads "This __question__ has been asked before and already has an answer.". The help center specifically says "we love (some) dupes. There are many ways to ask the same question, and _a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way_."

Comment: @TemaniAfif The point here is that Mehrdad was not helped by the "duplicate" question, and so closing their question as a "duplicate" was not beneficial to anyone, except maybe you if you enjoyed that sort of thing. It just feels like a judgemental slap in the face to a user looking for help. I also disagree with your assertion that SO can't provide answers such as "look at line 4." Sometimes that's what people need. This website is a resource to help each other - that's what we should focus on. Closing a question because *you* know the answer from reading a duplicate is pointless.

Comment: @SnailCadet: "*The point here is that Mehrdad was not helped by the "duplicate" question, and so closing their question as a "duplicate" was not beneficial to anyone*" I find it interesting that you went from what Mehrdad "was not helped by" to "was not beneficial to *anyone*", as if Mehrdad were somehow a stand-in for everyone.

Comment: @SnailCadet Utterly pointless. Not only does it not help the person who asked the question, it doesn't even help the hypothetical future googlers either. eg [the linked in the comment below this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253914/spring-social-authorisation-exception-with-facebook).

Comment: @NicolBolas I simply meant that it was Mehrdad's question, so Mehrdad was person who mostly stood to benefit from it being answered. Others might have benefited from answers/comments to the question, which could have differed from the "duplicate," if it had been left open. I don't see what anyone else gains from closing the question.

Comment: @SnailCadet actually, check that question and you will see that **I** am the one who helped mehrdad to solve his issue in the comments and then I find the needed duplicate question where he will find the full details about his issue. I could simply answer his question but it would be an abusive behavior to repeat the same answer already provided in another question

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry if my comment came across as an attack on you personally; I meant "you" in the proverbial sense of a user who closes comments. I see it as pointless for someone to come in and close a question because they understand the answer from "duplicates." I also see nothing abusive about answering a "duplicate" question; perhaps in a perfect world with identical duplicates it would make sense to keep only one answer, but in reality the nuances between questions differ. Often the combination of several very similar questions is what leads me to my own solutions.

Comment: I think there's a problem in how one would define a Reasonable User. I don't think that all reasonable users could be expected to know that Mehrdad's problem was in fact caused by the problem asked about in the linked questions. If Mehrdad had known that the cause for his problem was Quirks Mode he would not have had a problem to begin with.

Comment: The problem with the closure of Merdrad's question is actually that this question won't be able to help anyone facing the same issue in the future. There is just no way someone in the same situation finds this q/a or any of the dupes, just like Merdrad wasn't able to find them.

Comment: @Kaiido: I'm not sure I understand that. You seem to be saying that Mehrdad's question is simply bad, since it won't help anyone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: @NicolBolas not that it's a bad question no, it's definitely a problem one faces and a problem that is hard to identify at that. The question is well written too, so no I don't put any judgement on the quality. It is more SO model that fails here. We are at the border of "Won't help" and Duplicate.

Comment: @Jasper-M you forget that we have comment section. I first identified the problem in the comment section and then closed the question with a details one that explain this problem. I didn't close the question and leave the user to fight alone. I helped the user to identify the issue and linked to the relevant question.  Again, closing question will not kill the question. We can edit the question, discuss in comment, etc etc in order to argue or understand what is happening and reopen the question if needed.

Comment: @SnailCadet it seems that everyone here is *accusing* me to simply close the question and move one without care which is not the case. We have the comment section which is here for a purpose and its purpose is to discuss in order to clarify any ambiguity and this is what I did. I identified the issue, explained to the user his issue and after that I closed with a duplicate so he can better understand his issue. Anyone who will find this question can clearly understand the issue and find the solution. and clarification within the duplicate target

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think everyone here is taking issue with this hypothetical comment closer who, unlike you, closes the question as a duplicate and moves on. Unfortunately your particular case has gotten caught up in the argument because the question in question (ha) was linked. I don't take issue with how you handled the question (again, sorry for the tone of my earlier comment), but rather the idea that questions should be closed as duplicates at all, because it invites behavior like that of the hypothetical (though very real) question closer I described earlier.

Comment: @Kaiido `There is just no way someone in the same situation finds this q/a or any of the dupes, just like Merdrad wasn't able to find them.` : that's why we are here and we close as duplicate. It's not trivial to find that we are having an issue at the first place. Even if we do it's not trivial to know the name of that issue (the quirks mode in this case) but I was here to identify the missing piece of puzzle that will allow the user to understand what is happening. Considering the question, the comments and the duplicate the problem is solved (that's the goal)

Comment: @SnailCadet `I think everyone here is taking issue with this hypothetical comment closer who  closes the question as a duplicate and moves on`: the person who close a question doesn't have more power than the other. I faced a lot of gold badge owner badly closing questions and I reopened them. Any user can make mistake and the community can correct it. This is a needed feature and it can be missused by some users but this doesn't mean it should not be used at all. We should simply correct any *bad* behavior because we can open a question like we can close it.

Comment: I think the problem is the name _duplicate_. If P is the same as AQB (where A and B are easy), then P and Q are not really duplicate (duplicate means P = Q).  Borrowing [terminology from linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence), we could call P and Q _equivalent_

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's not true because often the people asking questions that get closed are newer users without those privileges. It's usually the case that a much more veteran SO user closes their question, further exacerbating the feeling that they're being spoken down to. Yes, the community can reopen erroneously closed questions, but I think the better solution is just not to close them as duplicates at all. Even if the questions are very nearly identical, what's wrong with having multiple answers?

Comment: `what's wrong with having multiple answers?` because this is not how SO works. We are not aiming to have a forum. We want to build a high quality question/answer repository where we need to minimize the duplication in order to have canonical question/answer that cover the most common issues. A comment won't be enough to explain the philosophy of SO but you will find a lot of meta question dealing with this and other person to explain this better than me.

Comment: @SnailCadet: "*what's wrong with having multiple answers?*" It spreads information around. It repeats information. It puts potentially less good versions of the same answer in different places, but without any scoring mechanism between them to make them compete. It makes it harder to find the best answer on Google because they're now spread among umpteen different questions. It wastes the time of the users who actually provide answers by encouraging them to answer things someone else already answered well. In short, it makes our site worse at doing its job.

Comment: @SnailCadet: "*You are being very aggressive and nonconstructive with your "why don't you post an answer" comments.*" No, I'm not. I'm asking you to discuss things the way the site is meant to have discussion meta questions work: if you have something significant to say on the subject, you put it in an answer where it can be discussed and voted on. That's the *opposite* of "nonconstructive".

Comment: @HansKilian it may be misused or used too hastly but many times the answer can be solve by copying the title of the question into Google and opening the top result which is a SO question about the very same thing. Other times the questions seem to be in the form of "Write my code for me". There are many tags I could contribute to but I don't because the people asking questions didn't put minimum amount of effort into Google. Other times the questions can be googled easily only if you know the correct term and then there is no blame on the user's side but still a duplicate.

Comment: @HansKilian The point of duplicates and closure is to keep good answers from being spread over 20 different questions.  It's not a slap in the face.  It's a way to keep from splintering information all over the place which is the mission statement of this site anyway.  If you have a good question for a duplicate, put it on the dupe-target.

Comment: What is your opinion on cases where problems **A** and **B** are non-trivial?  Personally, I think that typically means that the question is too broad.  An example is: "How do I store authenticated users in a database?" and their problems are that neither the authentication nor the database insertion is not working and they have example code for both, do you call it too broad and ask them to break it down to smaller chunks?

Comment: @zero: I would say that it depends very much on the nature of the question, as well as the relationship between the non-trivial components. In particular, if breaking down the problem is itself the non-trivial part, then the question deserves to stand on its own, even if multiple pieces are also non-trivial. If it really is just two (or more) independent, non-trivial problems, and the breakdown is fairly obvious, then yes, it's probably too broad.

Comment: I ran into a similar inverted P/AQB [last week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13492497/241211). Asker could not tell that the code he wanted was directly embedded in the answers to a slightly more complicated question. I tend toward the "close as dup" party, but it's nice to have a nudge for the right way to look at the answers in the dup target.

Comment: @TemaniAfif *"that's why we are here and we close as duplicate."* No. We are not here to answer to a single user. SO posts are meant to be found by future readers. A post that can not be found later by someone facing the same issue has no value in SO model. Closing as dupe is a mean to redirect the ones facing the same issue but using a different *wording* to a centralised pot of answers. In this case, it's not the wording that differs, but the whole symptoms. There is just no way that someone facing the same issue comes here with the same symptoms.

Comment: It even took an expert a few personal comments with the asker to find out the root cause. Are you saying we are an hotline for the whole internet? I don't think so. Now, **I** would probably have done the same as you did, but I'm pointing the fact that here your use of the hammer is actually just the same as a CommunityWiki linking to the 3 previous answers.

Comment: More general question:  *«what can be done to make it more clear to people that "exact duplicate" can refer to?»*  I wish there were a button *"Answer with existing solution"* instead of the *close -> Duplicate of* menu. In addition to the redirect for anonymous users, UI could be changed to preview/inline the corresponding solution (with its question excerpt, vote ↑↓). To encourage finding an existing solution (to collect improvements to the same problem in a single place)  instead of posting a new answer, the reputation may increase if the question author finds the suggested solution helpful

Comment: @jfs a little tidbit of history. Duplicate at the start could be against any question, even those without any answer. That's because the focus is that *the questions* are duplicates, not on the answers.

Comment: @Braiam if it was not forbidden explicitly; it doesn't mean it was ever a good idea.  Whether a question is a duplicate is defined by whether the corresponding solution fits. The focus is on the existing answers.

Comment: @jfs no. The focus has always been on the question, since the start. The only reason why it changed to require at least 1 positive scored or accepted answer was because people felt that it wasn't very useful to close newer questions against obscure older ones. The question is the one being closed.

Comment: @Braiam Can you provide an example of a *single* high quality, appropriate SO question where there is another question that has an answer to which, if the answer to the other question was posted to the first it would be a high quality, useful answer to the question, and to which the questions are fundamentally different questions?  Just one.  People like to keep saying all the time, that "Questions that are fundamentally different could still have the same answer" but I've yet to be given **even one** example of such a case, and I've thrown out this challenge many times.

Comment: @Servy You seem to have misunderstand me: if answer A solve problem P and Q, but answer B is the ideal solution to problem Q while A is ideal to P. This happens many times in SQL, read answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396/792066 In this case, P and Q only differ in the amount of rows for both.

Comment: If you consider having your question dupe-closed a "slap in the face", you should reevaluate why you use Stack Overflow. Is it to get answers to your questions, or is it to stroke your fragile ego?

Comment: Why aren't these questions just "Too Broad" for asking how to do several tasks and not being broken down ahead of time? That would cover cases when A and B are nontrivial as well. The questions you describe as basically "gimme teh codez" questions where the user has not put in the effort required.

Comment: @jpmc26: Because broadness has never been defined in terms of atomicity, or even "trivial" atomicity. Furthermore, having duplicates for related issues that boil down to a different one is useful, as it allows people to gain an understanding of how to break down problems. The recognition that this more general problem can be used to solve something that seems more specific.

Answer (score 37):

> Is this a good theory for the reasons some questions get closed as duplicates?

Yes, that is a rather eloquent way of describing it. A broad spectrum of questions break down into smaller issues, a very simple example being when `$` is undefined (not including the jQuery library). This leads to all sorts of A's and B's, but really solving Q will allow for perhaps some of the A's and B's to resolve themselves or at least be immediately discernible.

> Is it helpful to the site to close questions under this reasoning? My feeling is "yes", but it's useful to see arguments both for and against it.

Yes, it saves a lot of time, especially in the situations where solving Q is rather involved. We don't need to explain all of the in's and out's of serialization for every combination of [P,A,B] when PQ solves the problem.

There are, of course, times when a duplicate closure was incorrect, but these are overall a rather low occurrence.

> If your answer to #2 was "yes", what can be done to make it more clear to people that "exact duplicate" can refer to cases like these?

Of course, the power users of the site know that duplicate closure is correct (where applicable), but that does not mean that the "unreasonable user" knows that. The onus is on us to explain to those users the what and why of closure. In general, there has been a strong favoritism towards leveraging meta in these situations. The actual documentation in the help center is rather light weight.

Which brings us to the crux of your issue: how to explain the nuance. I think it must be done manually in the current environment.

As for any change to the environment, the auto-posting of the accepted answer in the linked duplicate has always been a favorite of mine. In addition, allowing the inclusion of multiple duplicates, where now we can link A, Q, and B as canonical solutions, really made progress for this situation.

Another route for change to consider would be a new close reason. I still am curious why the close reasons have remained essentially unchanged for so long. Perhaps an XY close reason would really do well here, where the XY closure was a link to a canonical post and had some verbage explaining the situation.

> When closing duplicates under this reasoning, is it useful to help explain to the OP how their question relates to the duplicate question? After all, they wouldn't have asked the question if they were a "Reasonable User" under this theory.

Sometimes, but it shouldn't be a requirement.

When I dupehammer I will generally explain *why* I chose the duplicate for a few reasons. One, I want other users to be able to know what direction I was going during closure. Two, I want to give the user whose question I just single-handedly closed an avenue to dispute; in my opinion it is my responsibility to reopen it if their reasoning for dispute is justified. Three, I am generally trying to help this person, so explaining how the duplicate applies to their situation (when it isn't just plain obvious) is still part of what I would consider to be common courtesy.

Comment: I hadn't read your answer before [posting mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384812/1438). I think we are coming at it from different angles and getting at the same conclusion. Auto-posting the accepted answer (or picking an answer as the duplicate target instead) is a really interesting idea.

Comment: @JonEricson - I agree, I think that is a strong path to follow, whichever version of it actually materializes.

Comment: @JonEricson yet that's bound to fail in many cases where the ideal solution for a problem isn't ideal for a similar but slightly tweaked problem. For example this [SQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329396/792066). The top answer would only work if there's an unique identifier for each row and I had a case before where I didn't have that, yet I needed those random rows.

Comment: @Braiam - Not having a way to index your table is a huge problem, and is a very rare edge case. Your assertion of "many cases" just sounds like arm waving. I would probably go with "in exceedingly rare cases" as a replacement. Keep in mind also, this just has to work well for a vast majority of cases, which it most likely does. Don't let perfection be the enemy of progress.

Comment: @TravisJ yet here we are, looking for the perfect asker that read everything we throw at him no matter how unreasonable the mental gymnastics has to be to connect what I'm reading with what I'm looking at. BTW, about that SQL question, you would notice that the order by rand() solution is a general one. It will work with anything you throw, even cases where you need a many to many random row (which natural ID is actually the relationship between two columns and it's considered good schema design).

Answer (score 20):

I think the problem we have on the XSLT area is that we get a lot of questions (about 650 at the last count) of the form "I wrote this code and I can't see why it doesn't work" to which the answer is "Your source document declares a default namespace". At one level of abstraction the questions are duplicates, but someone who doesn't know the answer doesn't have any hope of recognising them as duplicates, because the symptoms are different every time: the questions are superficially all different, the only thing they have in common is the answer. And even if you close as a duplicate, the user probably isn't going to understand why the effect was as observed in their particular case.

Part of the problem is that we have two quite different definitions to work with "this question is a duplicate" and "this question already has an answer". And related to this, there's a feeling that closing as a duplicate is a mild admonition: you should have found this before you asked. Which in this case is very unfair, because it's a usability flaw in the language design that every user falls into at least once on their learning curve.

And in practice, the people who answer questions on XSLT (including me) are very inconsistent about when to close as a duplicate, which means the number of distinct questions with "you have a default namespace" as the answer continues to multiply uncontrollably.

**AND TO ANSWER YOUR QUESTION(S):**

Your theory doesn't help me decide whether we should be closing these as duplicates. It might help in some situations, but not in this one.

Comment: Yes that's indeed a good and [common case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526389). I am not sure how one should handle such questions, because they actually don't fit in SE's model. We are here to build a **repository** of Q/A so that future readers can have their own question answered without having to post it here. Unfortunately for these the symptoms will be different for every users, and while they are good on-topic questions, they will also only ever help the asker. Closing as dupe is then just the easy way for the mjölnir holder to answer the asker without having to write up a CW.

Comment: You say "we are here to", but actually, we don't sign in blood that we are here for that purpose. My main purpose in being here is to help users who have problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." My own main purpose of being here (learn more about my job's field) doesn't matter. The goal of SE sites is still the same, tools are/should be made to serve this goal in priority. Being an hotline for desperate programmers is not the goal of SO.

Comment: When you do close as duplicate, do you find it helpful to comment on why? Or is it just easier to write a new answer and (maybe) link to the canonical question? I _think_ the OP's reasonable user theory would suggest not closing as a duplicate since reasonable people wouldn't be able to solve their problems with just the link. This seems to be a case where the software doesn't really support the problem y'all are faced with.

Comment: @Kaiido: "Being an hotline for desperate programmers is not the goal of SO." I can acknowledge that. I'd argue it's a necessary **function** of SO, though. It's a primary mechanism for getting questions. Rare, I would argue, are the cases where someone has solved their problem and then posts both question and answer here in a generous act for posterity.

Comment: @MathieuK. Ideally (and I'd argue it's already the case) most users of StackOverlow should **never** ask a single question, and when they do, most of the time, answerers should not have to spend one hour talking with the asker in order to find out what thing they did that wasn't in their question at first. That's what I mean by "being an hotline", and that's what a "My main purpose in being here is to help users who have problems." philosophy would lead SO to. It is by  building this library that we'll help all the anonymous users and that we really help *users that have problems*.

Answer (score 19):

### The theory is sound . . .

To use a concrete example, I found [the most common duplicate target](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/909952/most-common-duplicate-targets-for-a-tag?TopItems=10&TargetTag=shell) in a tag I know reasonably well. It was [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) Then I looked at the Linked questions in the sidebar and found [Assign output of curl to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764571/assign-output-of-curl-to-variable). Obviously the command used is immaterial and the askers of both questions are looking for either backticks or the `$(command)` Bourne shell syntax. A canonical question can have all the different variations collected in separate answers. So if you need to capture a multiline command, you don't need to ask another question; the solution is right there. And, of course, there's no need to duplicate answers over and over again if the reader can make a simple substitution of one command for another.

To [quote Joel](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/):

> Stack Overflow is not just a historical record of questions and answers. It’s a lot more than that: it’s actually a community-edited wiki of narrow, “long-tail” questions — questions that aren’t quite important enough to deserve a page on Wikipedia, but which come up over and over again.

### But it's not well supported by the software.

Of course, the problem needs to be very narrowly defined. If I need to capture both the output *and* any error messages produced by a command, I might need the answers to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) in addition to the canonical question. Will a reasonable user know how to redirect stderr to stdout? Perhaps. But it will make the duplicate question less useful for some subset of programmers who don't know (or don't remember) the syntax. Each additional complication reduces the odds closing the question will help the asker or subsequent readers.

We pondered closing questions with [links to Documentation examples](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328663/1438). (For those who don't know, Documentation was a [project that didn't work out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367572/1438).) But that quickly runs into the RTFM problem. Stack Overflow is more useful than most manuals because answers tend to be very focused on specific problems encountered by programmers. It would be a lot less useful if answers consisted of links to the appropriate section of the manual. It's not really all that different if the question is closed as a duplicate of more general question.

The closing system works well for "exact" duplicates, which is to say, the duplicate target solves the OP's problem with just a little extra information. But it doesn't work so well for duplicates that require extra knowledge to apply. Sometimes a comment can bridge the gap:

> You can do that with [backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash), but you might also want to take a look at how to [redirect stderr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file).

Unfortunately, people don't always do that and sometimes a real answer would be better.

### Speculative alternative.

Before Joe Friend moved on to greener pastures, he and I talked about a different way to think of duplicates. Instead of closing questions as duplicates, we considered **answering questions as duplicates**. The change in terminology is rather minor, of course. We could probably tweak some copy and call it a day. Very likely questions should still get closed to new answers since we'd want to direct people's efforts to making canonical resources. Exact duplicates (where the answer to one question answers another without the need to change anything) would be answered with nothing more than the link.

Thinking in these terms, it's more clear that closing as a duplicate when the target answers don't *exactly* answer the new question is equivalent to a link-only answer. It might not take much glue to connect the dots, but we don't have a good way to do that. To sort of sketch out the idea (don't get hung up on details) imagine if answering a question as a duplicate added a community wiki answer that used the verbiage of the banner we already use:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash/4651495#4651495)

It's not obvious, but the link is to an answer, not the question. Maybe we could even one-box it so readers won't have to follow a link or at least have an idea of where they are going. But since the answer can be edited (unlike a banner), people can add helpful bits of guidance:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>   [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash/4651495#4651495)
>
> Just substitute your curl command in the place that example uses `ls -1`.

That way we get the best of both worlds:

1. Askers and future readers get a clear picture of how the duplicate helps.
2. Answerers don't have to reinvent the entire wheel each time.

It may be better to let the first person to identify the duplicate own the answer and get reputation. (This is similar to a [*very long-standing request*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5).) It would also give someone a reason to fill in the gaps between what the asker is looking for and what the canonical answer says. And, of course, it's a better incentive to find duplicates than we have right now. (Again, the details are not worth quibbling over as this is highly speculative.)

### Thanks for formulating the theory.

We've been thinking about this for a very long time and I think this theory is a real breakthrough. To slightly rephrase so that I know we are on the same page:

A duplicate question is one where:

1. a reasonable user would be able to break the problem into subproblems that include the canonical question and
2. a reasonable user would be able to solve their problem given the duplicate because the other subproblems are trivial for them to solve.

So if the answer to the duplicate can be just a link to a canonical answer, this obviously an exact duplicate. If it requires several pages of explanation in addition to the link, it probably isn't.

Comment: I like the idea that if a question is closed as a duplicate you can post an answer in the form of a linked answer from one of the duplicates in the closure list. That sounds very nice. It could perhaps lead to users simply spamming all of the answers from the other post in hopes of reputation though, so there could be absolutely no reputation associated with doing that for the person posting the link only answer. One thing this fails to do is allow the canonical post content to receive votes. As noted, sometimes there are multiple answers in canonicals and the first one isn't always

Comment: the intended one. So to, if there are multiple duplicates linked where both are relevant and each solve very common problems, only showing one answer by default wouldn't be very beneficial. I think the easiest, and perhaps lowest hanging fruit effective, way to accomplish this would be to simply show all of the answers from the duplicates as answers to the current closed question, with full on comments and votes allowed. For these imported answers, show some sort of banner to indicate that they were imported. This would solve many problems. It would obliterate the idea of

Comment: answering a duplicate, because once closed the new answer would be buried under years of votes; it would allow the original content producers to benefit with votes on their content; it would allow the OP to feel like they got a large amount of answers immediately from Stack Overflow; it would allow that OP to choose which answer solved their problem, allowing for duplicate signposts to actually serve a broader purpose as well.

Comment: I am sure there are other benefits, but overall, just an empty closed question with a link (or just a link only answer in the form of duplicate closure) clearly has a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: "actually a community-edited wiki of narrow" sadly, the community is very against this. Any edit on any post that deviates from formatting/spelling is seen as "changing the intent"/"putting words in the OP mouth". If you want that vision become a reality SE needs to make stronger wordings that such edits are not only welcomed, but encouraged and the tooling that accompanying this. [I recommended some solutions towards this tooling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575) which would help such message.

Comment: "a reasonable user would be able to break the problem into subproblems that include the canonical question" that's not any user. In fact that's the rarest of the users, and are usually on the answerer side, precisely because they are capable of doing so. I prefer breaking ourself the question instead of expecting the asker to be able to do so.

Comment: I think that (Jon's) wording that @Braiam points to is actually ambiguous - does the "able to break the problem into..." happen *before* or *after* the OP is pointed to the duplicate? Imagine you have a problem that can be solved using algorithm X. You don't know about the algorithm X, so you cannot break your problem down into steps that involve X. But once you get pointed to its existence, it's easy to apply it to your problem.

Comment: The theory is not complete, however, as I set out in my answer. It considers the case of a question P that can be broken into AQB. This is in one direction, where a question is asked that has not be properly reduced to its minimal example. Sometimes, someone asks a new question that _has_ been broken into its minimal examples, but its scope overlaps with a more general problem that has been answered. It then gets closed, usually unhelpfully, in favour of the more general problem. I gave examples too.

Comment: And the reason I say it is unhelpful to close a specific problem as a limiting case of a more general problem is _it could well be the specific example that most people want the answer to_. By closing that question, people are not allowed to add newer, superior answers to the specific problem _unless they have a solution to the general problem as well_. And this is to the detriment of quality, because it (1) encourages people not to provide newer, superior answers to the specific problems ; and (2) to keep asking the same questions over and over, because people don't see the general Q&A.

Comment: @JiriTousek: Yeah. There is an element of "aha!" in some of these duplicates, isn't there? (Reminds me of those not-so-helpful interview questions that turn on some trick not everyone has seen before.)

Comment: @Braiam: Being able to break up large problems into smaller ones is a debugging skill that seems not to be taught as well as it could be. I think we are on the same page in thinking duplicate closers sometimes overestimate this skill in others. Sometimes there are coding patterns (like pipelines in shell programming) that help break down problems and might not be known to programmers new to the language.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: Yes, I agree that many times closing a specific problem to point to a general problem is the equivalent of a link-only answer. (One that is safe from downvotes and deletion. And is posted _above_ the question itself.)

Comment: @JiriTousek no, the wording is correct. Jon got what I'm at. Breaking a problem into smaller ones is a rare skill on the site, and usually not found in askers. That's why I don't believe in this theory, since it takes as axiom that most users are able to break down problems into smaller ones.

Comment: @Braiam: "*it takes as axiom that most users are able to break down problems into smaller ones.*" It makes no claims about "most users". The axiom is that *reasonable users* should be expected to be able to do it. Or more specifically, it presupposes a minimum standard of competence for people searching for programming issues. Users below this standard will not be well served by this site.

Comment: @NicolBolas then you need to make the site by invitation only. Or by testing. The site doesn't work that way and you need to take that into account to make your axioms. If *anyone* can ask a question, then *anyone* have to be well served by this site. If you don't put any conditional (ie. that you have to be a reasonable user) to joining the site, then you are only furthering the clashes between expectations.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If "reasonable users" is not a majority of readers, I think closing as duplicate will substantially harm the usefulness of the site. For instance, I have used HTML and CSS for many years, but [this example that's been tossed around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526389/why-doesnt-font-size-propagate-from-div-to-table) took a lot more deciphering for me than it should have to understand what was going on. I don't think it helps to define "reasonable" as "having answered the same basic question over and over". Better to have link-only answers, which can be edited at least.

Comment: @Braiam: "*If anyone can ask a question, then anyone have to be well served by this site.*" Remember the lesson of Ratatouille: "anyone can cook", but not *everyone can cook*. We let anyone try, and we try to tell people what they need to succeed, but if they fail, then *they fail*.

Comment: @NicolBolas the thing is that we tell them that "you can cook". We are telling them that your question, will *always* be welcomed, since there's 0 barrier of entry (and no, creating an account an clicking a checkbox isn't an effective one). What we need to make your theory sound is [a level of meta-cognition](https://xkcd.com/810/) that we, the community, are unable to provide with the tooling on the site. The most effective questions are those that prevent questions from even being asked, which is why self-help spoon fed questions are crucial. What SO inc. can do is another matter altogether.

Comment: @Braiam: Most forums don't have much of a barrier to entry, but most forums also have posting requirements. Ours may be a bit more involved, but they're *still there*. Why should we be required to accept whatever, when forums and such get to cull out inappropriate stuff? "*which is why self-help spoon fed questions are crucial*" Um, no. Those questions don't prevent other questions from being asked, because they're *so specific* that nobody else will ever have that exact problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas why are you ignoring the modifier on the "barrier of entry". I specifically called for a effective barrier of entry. SO doesn't have one. There isn't anything that prevents you from asking a question if a condition isn't fulfilled. The quality filters are the nearest approximation but there's just so much you can do with parsing free text without triggering false positives. A barrier of entry in the case of SO is something that *prevents you from even posting* without fulfilling a criteria.

Comment: @Braiam: The Reasonable User theory is not about the person asking the question; we don't care much about them. It's about a hypothetical Reasonable User who has the same problem and comes across that question. If having that duplicate there solves the problem for this Reasonable User, then it's OK to mark that question a duplicate.

Comment: @NicolBolas so... who are we, then? Remember, a model is a representation (or simplification) of the reality. Who would be those that aren't the "reasonable user", because, even Jon Skeet has had some questions. **How your theory fits in the real world?**

Comment: @Braiam: It seems that you're not understanding what the theory is. The Reasonable User theory is a theory for answering the question "is this duplicate closure valid?". That's *all it does*. It's right there in the title: it's a theory about duplicate questions. The theory determines validity by hypothesizing a "reasonable user" and asking if such a user could get the answer they need if they have the problem indicated by the question. If they could, then the closure is valid. The theory doesn't care about who is or is not a reasonable user, only about the characteristics of such a user.

Answer (score 13):

I have a dupehammer for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) - if I dupe hammer something I normally leave a comment with a TL;DR of the dupe, because I know that most 1-rep question posters do not take the time to read the dupe / would not understand it immediately.

They still should read it to learn from it, but that's what I would do.

> 1. Is this a good theory for the reasons some questions get closed as duplicates?
> 2. Is it helpful to the site to close questions under this reasoning? My feeling is "yes", but it's useful to see arguments both for and
>      against it.

Yes

> 3. If your answer to #2 was "yes", what can be done to make it more clear to people that "exact duplicate" can refer to cases like these?

There are quite a few mistakes/problems that Python novices make:

- mixed indentation
- Why does my recursive function return None?
- How to get input and validate it
- My lists of list changes if I change one list inside it
- nested list comprehension
- group list of objects by attribute of object
- ...

etc. - all these have good canonical dupes.

Sometimes there is a "my list of dicts changes all dicts if I add something to one of them" which could be such a P/Q situation - the reason [is the same as for the canonical for lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) - but the first reaction is:

NO - I use lists, not dicts, that's not a dupe at *all*. If the dupe needs "thinking" it might need a slightly bigger comment to make it plausible.

> 4. When closing duplicates under this reasoning, is it useful to help explain to the OP how their question relates to the duplicate question?

Yes. Most of the time.

Sometimes the question is more of a (P1, P2, P3, P4) problem (the OP might not even recognize that P2-P4 exist) in which case I might add 2-3 dupetargets and explain which one would solves what part of the problem and ask for the future to only ask specific problem. If not all problems can be dupes, I suggest creating a new questions with *that* specific problem if it can not be solved...

Comment: Completely agree with the comment directly connecting the two questions. I find this can frequently appease the question asker as they get their answer without having to think. My preferred go-to is to actually **apply** the duplicate to their question and link to a runnable playground with the customized solution. This has the benefit of forcing me to see if the duplicate truly applies, if there are any missing pieces of the duplicate, etc.

Comment: "because I know that most 1-rep question posters do not take the time to read the dupe": do we really want those kinds of people here? People, who when pointed towards the answer to their question, can not be bothered to read it? I say no, and therefore encouraging them to stay by spoon-feeding them just makes the problem *worse*.

Comment: @Raedwald my unfounded hope is, that those 1rep ppl are 10-12y old and growing into coding. They do not know of API, documentation or how to look things up. By showing basic curtesy we can nip certain ill begotten behavior patterns in those that stay around, even if their original question gets closed. We can foster good behaviour and educate. They eventually will gain rep and maybe contribute to SO as whole - if we do not raise some new ones well grow old and die. For those repeatead "gimme code, curese around" type of visitors - I agree, not much need for them to stick around.

Comment: @PatrickArtner This site is for professional and enthusiast programmers. Not for children learning to code. Pandering to their weaknesses is not constructive. They need a teacher, not a Q&A site.

Comment: @Raed at age 12 I was already an enthusiast programmer - Dos and Basic but non the less ... but I had to use books, Internet was not really a thing. I try to be "more welcoming" which is the new thing to be. _enthusiast_ programmer this-a-days means I can click together code from different tutorials and want to code - not _I have a basic idea what this code does and understanding what I do_. My daughter (13) starts coding (https://scratch.mit.edu/) and might have questions as well - I just hope she asks me first before asking here ...

Answer (score 6):

This would be a pretty radical change, and it's just brainstorming for now. This was inspired by [Servy's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384711/the-reasonable-user-theory-of-duplicate-questions?cb=1#comment694475_384711):

> A lot of people just don't like the idea of their question being closed at all. I've seen people complain when their question is closed as a duplicate, **only to be super grateful of someone posting an answer with exactly the same information** in the duplicate to their question. They (often correctly) assume that their question being considered a duplicate means they did something wrong, so they get defensive and do everything they can to fight it, rather than trying to figure out how to solve their problem using the answers on the duplicate.

I don't know exactly how this would work, but rather than showing the OP that their question has been closed as a duplicate, *display the answers of the duplicate as answers to **their** question*.

This presents the information they need where they want to see it. Perhaps you could have something where when they "accept" one of the displayed answers, it fully closes their question as a duplicate (à la clicking the "Yes this is a duplicate button").

The downside is that the user wouldn't have such a clear understanding that they made a mistake in asking a duplicate - as I said, this idea certainly needs a lot of tweaking!

Comment: This has been proposed a number of times, but there would be quite a lot of work in order for something like this to even have a shot at working, so I wouldn't have high hopes for it until SE makes spending considerable development effort on new Q/A features something they're open to doing.

Comment: Still, that's like, possibly the thing I've heard about duplicates in the last year that would be the closest to working, insofar as working means "user whose question is closed is not angry".

Comment: Something that SE already does is silently redirect anonymous users to the dupe target.  Came in through the dupe, show you the target and it's answers.  It solves most of this without issue; the logged in users can follow the link if they want to.

Comment: @fbueckert yes - it doesn't doesn't solve the issue of the OP getting annoyed.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, this is a pretty big project to try and solve an issue which isn't critical. I'm sure there are better, cheaper solutions.

Comment: I am uninterested in solving that problem, @Tim.  I am more focused on creating a repository that can help far more than one user, so if that's the cost of building our [cabinet castle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378863/1197934), I'm alright with that.

Comment: @fbueckert If users aren't behaving appropriately, the system is wrong, and needs fixing. Getting frustrated when their questions are closed means we are doing *something* wrong when we explain what's happened and why. As Servy says - users are happy when the answer is posted in duplicate.

Comment: Setting expectations can help with that, but from my experience, there are always users who don't want to put in effort to help themselves, and want to be spoonfed an exact answer.  You can't get rid of those people, and no system changes will ever induce them to change.  Can't call them help vampires anymore, but that's what they are.  That's hyperbole for many, I know, but not every symptom is a problem that should be fixed.

Comment: @Tim People complain about having to pay taxes, about having to follow laws, about all *sorts* of things that make everyone, including the one complaining, better off.  There is no possible complex system for a large population that can be designed that won't result in anyone ever complaining or getting frustrated.  By your own logic, since there are lots of users complaining about, and being frustrated by, people frequently posting duplicates, so we need to do something about it and fix that problem.

Comment: @Servy yes, I agree. We need to do something. And you might get people who are annoyed by having to pay taxes. Nobody should be frustrated by the process of doing so (i.e make it as easy as possible to pay them correctly).

Comment: In my opinion, showing the user a boatload of high quality answers to their question would immediately offset the frustration of closure. Often, users seem to confuse their question being closed as a duplicate as not receiving an answer or any help; whereas most power users know it is a pain to find the duplicate to close with. Showing the answers would alleviate the users feeling of that in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Is this a good theory for the reasons some questions get closed as duplicates?

Yes.

> 2. Is it helpful to the site to close questions under this reasoning?

Sometimes, but there are some caveats.

- If specific problem P permits alternative solutions *other* than breaking it down into A, Q, and B, then it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of Q, even if breaking it down into A, Q, and B is a valid approach.
- Even if a problem P can be in some sense broken down into subproblems A, Q, and B, you still shouldn't close P as a duplicate of Q unless the task of applying a solution to Q *within the specific context of problem P* is trivial. If Q is quite an abstract problem and P is quite a concrete one, then figuring out the "do Q" step may be hard even with a complete solution to Q in front of you.

To show what I mean by these points, imagine that you ask *"How can I parse each URL in a list in Fooscript and print each of their hostnames?"* and I close it as *"How to parse a formal syntax using regex in Fooscript"*. There is a sense in which this perfectly fits your closure model; A is "loop over the list", Q is "parse with regex" and B is "print the result". But such a closure is obviously unhelpful, both because there are probably better approaches like using a built-in URL parsing function in Fooscript or a URL-parsing library, and because even if you *do* take the regex-based approach, it's non-trivial to take an answer to the generic question of "how do I parse stuff?" and apply it to parsing some specific thing.

Are there even more caveats I'm missing? Probably. In particular, I view the word "trivial" in your description with suspicion and worry that one user's idea of what tasks are "trivial" may differ drastically from another's.

I guess that the broad underlying rule should be that X is a duplicate of Y if and only if any reasonable person looking for a solution to X will, after reading a good answer to Y, feel like X has been solved and they need no further help. Any attempt to break that down into a more detailed formula for establishing duplicateness is likely to go wrong in some edge cases.

(Aside: am I attacking strawmen by implying that anyone would follow the sort of perverse and literalistic interpretation of your Reasonable User Theory implied by the hypothetical closure of the URL-parsing question above? No, I don't think so; I've been told in all seriousness before that [all parsing questions are ultimately the same](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342959/should-we-burninate-chemistry/342970#comment454381_342970).)

> 3. If your answer to #2 was "yes", what can be done to make it more clear to people that "exact duplicate" can refer to cases like these?

First of all, note that we don't use the phrase "exact duplicate" anywhere any more. The close reason just uses the word "duplicate". That matters slightly, because "exact duplicate" would just be clearly factually wrong in this scenario, so it's good that we don't use that wording. Anyway, leaving that point aside...

Which people? Close-voters, or askers?

You can probably make it clearer to the former group by, uh, posting a Meta Stack Overflow discussion of the Reasonable User Theory, which you've done. Beyond that, I'm not sure how wise it is to make it clearer, because I fear it's an easy-to-abuse rationale for closure; while I don't want to *stop* people from using it, I don't want to give them blanket encouragement to do it, either.

As for how to make it clearer to askers... I think that's *also* a misguided question. The things I'd want to make clearer to askers are:

- The close-voters believe that reading the duplicate will fully answer the asker's question
- The closure is meant as a way of helping them and future readers by directing them to useful existing content, not as a reprimand, and doesn't harm them or necessarily reflect poorly on them in any way
- If the closure is wrong and the other post is really not a duplicate, they have recourse available through editing, flagging, or asking on Meta

Why would we *want* to make clearer that the closure was in compliance with our community norms and rules? Isn't that entirely unimportant compared to making clearer that the closure is meant to be *helpful*, including to the asker whose question was closed, and that they have recourse if it wasn't?

> 4. When closing duplicates under this reasoning, is it useful to help explain to the OP how their question relates to the duplicate question?

Yes. Even if it is reasonably obvious, and even if the asker truly is a Reasonable User who's capable of figuring it out themselves, adding a couple of sentences spelling it out is helpful and courteous.

> After all, they wouldn't have asked the question if they were a "Reasonable User" under this theory.

That doesn't *necessarily* follow. Perfectly reasonable, conscientious, intelligent users still ask exact duplicates of existing questions simply because they failed to find them, perhaps due to using different terminology.

But sure, if the user is not "Reasonable", that's all the more reason to give them an extra nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

Just be careful when you define reasonable user. I do agree with the general theory, as it is a concise way to avoid duplication of very similar questions. That said, what seems trivial to one user may not seem trivial to another.

Here on SO, we deal with a very broad variety of ability levels and while it may seem easily apparent to the user marking it as a duplicate that problem P can be solved using steps from the solution to problem Q, the question asker may not understand that that's the case. It can be helpful to clarify in the comments before closing. If you link to the other question and OP immediately understands, then close it and move on. But you may encounter a reasonable user trying to ask a good question but who does not have the level of expertise to understand the answer to problem Q, in which case it may make sense to answer P at an appropriate level of complexity.

Answer (score -3):

There appears to be a mindset that questions and answers have a 1-1 relationship. That is just not true. In fact it is an n-1 relationship. Any number of questions can have the same answer, and not even be related, or only related tangentially. Sometimes the relationship is obvious only to the answerer, particularly if that answerer is really smart, or highly experienced. Unfortunately, the asker is generally not Sheldon Cooper and they generally have much less specific experience than the hammerer. In my opinion too many questions are marked as a duplicate even when they should not be, or should only marked as a duplicate with an explanation of the relationship between the question and the marked duplicate.

Mehrdad brings up an excellent example. The question was "why do the fonts on my page not behave as expected". All of the answers linked as duplicates are variations on "what is quirks mode, and how does it work?" All of the answers to these questions indicate that Quirks mode is a thing that was come up with to deal with differences in the IE5 markup vs. the standard. And while it may be true that turning on or off Quirks mode may have fixed the problem that Mehrdad was having, "Because quirks mode" only tangentially answers Mehrdad's question, and there is no indication in any of the answers in the linked duplicate questions that would tell a user the mechanics of how quirks mode is responsible for the behavior Mehrdad was experiencing. Thus I would classify any of those answers as low quality answers for the question.

If we want high quality answers, we need to tailor those answers to the question at hand, not just say "because quirks mode" now you go figure out what I mean by that.

Don't get me wrong. I am not advocating writing the same answer everywhere. What I am saying is this is the internet age. Create a new answer, and acknowledge the other great answers to other questions by linking to them in your answer, but don't stop there. Answer the question "how does this apply to me?" in your answer.

For example, instead of hammering that question about font irregularities with a question about quirks mode and leaving it at that, an answer that said something like:

It looks like you are running up against Quirks mode. You can find a discussion about that here, but the reason it can cause the behavior you are seeing is ... and here is what you can do to prevent it ...

Now tangentially questions are linked, the asker has an answer he can understand and use immediately, and the googler who has no idea to ask a question about quirks mode instead of the funky font behavior he is seeing can find help. Everyone wins, and SO is better for it.

Comment: So, you seem to be fine if 90% of an answer is just copied from another location. If the answer is "Here's a long explanation of what Quirks mode is," followed by "Here's a paragraph about how Quirks mode applies to this specific situation", that is a good and productive thing for users to do. That seems to be what you're saying.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I will edit my answer.

Comment: again and again .. I am the hammer of the Mehrdad question and I already did what you said in the comment section. I highlighted the issue in the comment section and then added the relevant question as a duplicate. So the question + the comments + the duplicate are all the needed information to understand and fix the issue. As @NicolBolas said, it won't be productive to add an answer to simply say *you are having a quirk mode issue, read about it here*. This will never be a good answer , it's a comment.

Comment: @TermaniAfif so you are saying that comments don't ever go away, and that answers located in comments are sufficient?

Comment: it's not an answer located in comment, it's a comment that gives a hint about the issue and the duplicate question contain the answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I read through it all and suddenly you say "quirks mode" add this. No mention of what brought you to that revelation, or why "quirks mode" is the answer. The answers linked do not provide this information either, and I am aware of what quirks mode is. I would prefer to see a real answer that links back to quirks mode and expands a little about what brought you to this conclusion. That would actually help a lot more than "quirks mode". I have no idea how to apply this or even if it can be applied to other situations from this comment.

Comment: @TemaniAfif in my mind this is a give a man some code vs. teach a man to code. If all we do is give code without relevant rationale, then we are inviting gimme te codz questions.

Comment: I said this: `ok, I see, quirks mode .. you are not adding the doctype at the top` then if you check the first duplicate you can read: `Generally, quirks mode is turned on when there is no correct DOCTYPE declaration, and turned off when there is a DOCTYPE definition` and `Quirks mode is not, however, a standard. The rendering of any page in quirks mode in different browsers may be different.` --> I guess those 3 sentences are more than clear to understand what is happening and to explain the unwanted output

Comment: Your scenario here seems very close to the one I described for XSLT: lots of different questions/problems/symptoms with the same root cause: failure to understand or appreciate the significance of (or even be aware of) a particular feature/bug in the language design. And the problem is then the tension between creating a lasting and valuable repository of knowledge, versus helping the user who is stuck with a programming problem.

Comment: Common sense. Hence the down votes - we wouldn't want to be seen to be actually helping someone, after all, would we?  (I was challenged above as to why I haen't answered, given I have an opinion. Frankly, I wouldn't dare. I got 79 down votes last time I did answer on this topic.)

Comment: @MatthewTaylor, I just saw your 79-times downvoted answer. Unbelievable, as I noted in a comment under it. I would appreciate your feedback on my answer below, specifically just the section "not complete".

Comment: @TemaniAfif: The [comment on that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55526389/why-doesnt-font-size-propagate-from-div-to-table#comment97757550_55526389) plus closing seems about as useful as a link-only answer. I wasn't aware of quirks mode (which sounds like a setting you might turn on in your browser rather than the way the browser handles some documents), but I was able to figure it out after flipping back and forth. It doesn't seem like not answering has saved you very much time or effort compared to writing an answer that links to the other questions.

Answer (score -3):

I think that most of questions are duplicate for such a reason that question simply already exists and already has an answer. While it works most of times, there are plenty of archived questions which has been answered, whose solutions no longer work, and the issue is they are still referred to as duplicates. That's understandable, but those question can be no longer answerable, no longer commentable. And also, beware that new users can't comment on someone else's question, which is also why they make duplicate questions. Seriously, I am like 30 reputation points from reaching that goal post when I can comment on question of someone else. I can post answer, but to tell simply those solutions no longer work and I'd like to hear of solutions that work, that defeats the purpose. And if I specifically state in a question that the original no longer works, eighter gets closed as duplicate or gets completely ignored. I am convinced that those admins read the title and say "that's duplicate", without even reading the content. Seriously? I'm waiting for your defense...

Comment: Closing doesn't prevent anyone from commenting.

Comment: @TinyGiant Maybe. However as a newbie I do not have privilegium to comment on someone's else question. But I must admit that 99 % of questions deserve to be closed as duplicates. People are just too lazy to search for their issues before asking.

Comment: Errr... I'd like to see some evidence for "99 % of questions deserve to be closed as duplicates". That seems rather outlandish and unrealistic.

Comment: @TinyGiant Maybe. But still, it's majority of questions.

Comment: I'd still want to see some evidence to that effect before I'd believe it. I doubt it. If that were true there would be 0 incentive to contribute new answers and all of the answerers would then leave. Given that the majority of curators are answers, the vast majority of the curators would leave, then it would be a ghost town. Regardless, this question isn't about what percentage of questions asked every day are duplicates. It is about how duplicate closure is intended to work, designed to work, and how it is applied in the field, so the point you're trying to make is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @TinyGiant This is going nowhere. I tried to make my opinion and let you decide agree or disagree. I wrote MY point of view as from the one who asks. Because like all my questions were marked duplicates (one of them legitimately, because eighter my question was a little bit different, or the old one was a little bit outdated and I needed an updated solution that works).

Answer (score -6):

As someone who has been the architect of many canonical questions (i.e. that were constructed from the ground up to be used as canonical), I think I can share my experience.

When I design a canonical question, I don't think about "the questions that should be closed against this question", but "how to solve a common problem". In fact, I've crafted canonical questions for which you have to ask a very specific high level question to be considered a duplicate of that question (in particular [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121180/what-information-do-i-need-to-solve-an-apt-dependency-issue) which while it has many linked questions, only one is marked as duplicate (and that one is in the process of being deleted)).

Now, there are several types of canonical questions:

- Question that asks how to solve issue Q. Only questions which are semantically equivalent can be closed as duplicate of this one.
- Questions that asks about how to diagnostic issue Q. These are very important, but they aren't duplicate targets themselves. They are the comment which are company of close as unclear votes. The issue may be caused by any number of reasons, but without figuring out which of those are, no one can know which is the solution. That's the case of the example that I linked above.
- List of solutions. These are the worst. These are unfocused Q&A where >90% of the information contained isn't relevant to the people looking to solve their issue or answer their question.
- Characteristics of finite X. These are weird beasts. They address a common moving target, but that moving target doesn't grow. This is the only one [I know of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop) that is actively being used as duplicate target.

Those are the kind of questions I consider that could be canon by the definition I laid out above. This gives us a finite amount of iterations.

- When a question is asking about issue Q, it's closed against the question that solves issue Q.
- When a question is about problem P, which is a collection of symptoms unique to issue Q, is closed as duplicate of the question that solves Q.
- When a question is about problem P, which is a collection of symptoms that can be solved by Q, A or B; it's closed as unclear what you are asking and a comment is posted asking to provide more information to determine whenever a solution for Q, A or B should be given.
- When a question is about problem P, which is a collection of symptoms that can be solved by the combination of solutions E, G and H; if we can pinpoint the specific symptoms to each of the possibles solution, remove the symptoms for which the solution already exist (let’s say E and G exist with their finite list of symptoms), and the question becomes about solving the symptoms of H. In case questions already exist for E, G and H, then close it as too broad. Linking duplicates would be a waste of time for the future reader since the redirection isn't deterministic on which of the question they should read to solve their problem. And no, linking multiple duplicates doesn't help either.
- Issue S is a specific subset of a broader, but finite, question. The subset is finite and stable. Between each subset only X change, but the parameters of each is the same. That's the case of [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop), where Ubuntu is the name of the distribution, which has many flavors (subsets). Each flavor has finite characteristics that are shared between them and only vary in the specific values these characteristics can take. The issue S is knowing the requirement to run each of them. Duplicates asking for issue S about subset X can be closed as duplicate of this one.

Note that in those iterations duplication only happens when the question fulfills several conditions: 1) it's specific; 2) it's clear; and 3) it's already asked. That means that unclear questions and too broad questions would never be sources or destinations.

As I explained above, the "reasonable user" doesn't even *need to exist*. If the destination is of high quality, the reader will always find its issue solved by the canonical question without being inundated of irrelevant information.

For that reason, the "reasonable user" theory fails. It's creates unnecessary bickering and a waste of the expert energy arguing their point. Duplicate questions are better when they are questions asking about the same thing, not just when the answer may be the same.

Comment: You could include the famous *[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384)* (Java) and *[What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142)* (.NET) questions.

Comment: @PeterMortensen while I agree that those questions must exist, the amount of times it gets reasked cast doubts about the implementation. Heck, only in the last 24 hours there has been 13 new questions asked, which in some way are referencing the NPE Java one.

Answer (score -11):

This question asks about the case of a user with problem P, that is closed in favour of an apparently-different problem Q, where P can be broken down into A, Q, B.

I agree that many problems are like this, and in general, I don't see a problem with closing as a dupe, if P differs from AQB only by A and B, both of which are well understood and trivial.

#### Not complete

It is not the full story about typical dupe closures, however. It fails to consider the other direction, where the user who asks a question D, which is closed as a dupe of canonical problem R, where R can be further broken down into C, D, E (and C, D, E may or may not overlap with each other in scope too).

In this case, D is the more "atomic" question, and it is closed as a limiting case of a more general question.

Here is one example:

- R: (very difficult in the general case) "*How can I encode a string in a Bash variable such that it can be safely passed into a sed `s///` command?*".

A solution to this (real life) problem can also solve these much simpler problems:

- C: (easiest, and most frequently asked) "*How can I encode a string in a Bash variable such that any forward slashes that it may contain will be properly escaped when passed to sed's `s///` command?*"
- D: (harder) "*How can I encode a string in a Bash variable such that it can always safely be passed to the *replacement* in sed's `s/regex/replacement/`*"?
- E: (harder again) "*How can I encode a string in a Bash variable such that it can safely be passed as the *regex* in sed's `s/regex/replacement/`*"?

Solving the general problem R here is really, really hard. The answer to that question, unsurprisingly, is very long.

Of course, someone who knows they only need to escape the forward slashes will not want a complicated function in their code that solves the general problem. That would be over-engineering.

99% of the time, the user, for better or for worse, just wants to know C.

A better theory, therefore, needs to consider this type of dupe closure too.

#### Reasonable users

Reasonable person test?

While I agree with the general approach suggested for the case P = AQB, I find the idea of the "reasonable user" problematic. It seems to be the "reasonable person" test borrowed from law, but upended. The "reasonable person" in law is not supposed to possess any skills of deductive logic. Quite the opposite. The "reasonable person" is supposed to be the person who thinks and behaves just like any other reasonable person.

If users of this site were "reasonable" in the sense proposed by the OP, duplicates mostly wouldn't be asked. That questions are repeatedly asked that get closed for one reason or other suggests that most of our visitors - including those asking, and those reading in the archives - are *not* reasonable in this sense.

It seems to me that reasonable isn't the right word; what the OP really means is *ideal* user, the user we wish was the typical one. This definition of "reasonable" makes the "reasonable user" exceptional; and the typical user "unreasonable".

After all, it is eminently *reasonable* to simply want to get your job done, as fast as possible. There is the *typical user*.

Trivial is a matter of opinion

Also, things that are obvious to me aren't always obvious to others. Sometimes I find myself surprised by this.

While there may have been widespread agreement in whatever prompted this question to be asked here, it is often the case that whether or not something is a dupe divides the community here down the wire.

#### A better approach

Naturally, the simplest and best approach, that would probably solve all arguing and all problems, would be to do exactly what every other company in the world does, when building its internal Q&A databases and knowledge bases- *defer to the judgement of the customer/consumer/asker*.

*Just ask them if they are happy to have their question closed as a dupe*.

"The customer is always right". 9 times out of 10, the customer will be flexible about this. Occasionally, the asker will just disappear and not reply, in which case their question will be closed because they never came back.

Note that in the comments, it is argued that this won't work, based on observations that askers almost never support duplicate close votes on their questions. I think the reason for this is that there's a big difference between helpfully asking someone if the duplicate you found helps them; and unilaterally voting to close their question. The former is likely to elicit cooperativeness ; the latter defensiveness.

Occasionally, the asker will be difficult, obstinate, obtuse etc and demand an answer to a question that was already asked. Big deal. Either someone will answer it, or not. If not, the question gets closed in a few days anyway. A win for everyone, and nothing to argue about.

Comment: "And occasionally, the asker will be difficult, obstinate, obtuse etc and demand an answer to a question that was already asked." That is more the norm, than the exception.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, all I can say is it isn't like that in the real world, businesses don't face these issues managing their internal tools, so it could be that SO's community is so unwelcoming with the close/down votes that it causes people to be obstinate etc.

Comment: That is an insanely broad and uncited claim you make there. You have insight in the majority of business on Earth? And more importantly, this is not your typical profit oriented business, the comparison you make falls short in most regards.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, I think the sample of businesses and more relevantly the large sample of people in them I met in my 20 years is representative. When you find yourself saying that _most_ people are obstinate, etc- obviously they’re not. I mean by definition. If most people were obstinate, obstinate would be normal, and we wouldn’t have a word “obstinate” that describes a deviation from the norm. It’s SO, not everyone else.

Comment: You are not the only one with experience, and you are most definitely obstinate. Why do you make your experience and sample more important than that of others?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, I guess that makes me normal then. I think the main point is the majority of people simply can’t be obstinate, by definition of the terms.

Comment: Ah yes, that's reasonable, I think I get what you mean. I believe the nuance I'd like to see here however, is that we are *online*. If one looks shortly on Twitter, Facebook, or other forum with high use, I think it becomes apparent that in these contexts, the "norm" is everyone is super obstinate, or at least that's been my experience.

Comment: Oh by the way, I realize I myself am most definitely obstinate, and to an extent, I think we all should have a healthy degree of obstination. My general feeling about your answer, is that while you say (iiuc) that we should count on users to not be obstinate or obtuse, and act in "good faith" about their question, I have a different experience of what we can expect from users on Stack Overlow, and on the Internet generally.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, thanks for the thoughtful comments. I think you are right that online forums bring out the worst in people, and I also think it is not the _default_ behaviour of people to be super obstinate- even online. Something has to set them off, and when most people get to the point of asking on Stack Overflow, they're probably already feeling frustrated by a problem, and I can totally understand that it might take nothing more than one close or down-vote on their question to set that person off.

Comment: Problem with trying to cater to user majority is that it runs **directly** counter to the repository we're building.  *Of *course all users are going to tell you their questions are special and different, and should not be duped.  They're biased, and most often, do not understand, nor care, about the goal of the site.  Their voice is limited to their ability to persuade and edit.  The rest comes with privileges, which they can then exercise as they see fit.  If we let askers decide, SO would've died a long time ago.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*If users of this site were "reasonable" in the sense proposed by the OP, duplicates mostly wouldn't be asked.*" I mentioned that in question 4. But more importantly, the "reasonable user" theory applies to the question, not the person asking it. That is, marking it as a duplicate should help the "reasonable user"; whether the OP qualifies for that label is essentially irrelevant.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the trouble is, SO is not generally for experts. If P is the same as AQB, I expect that experts will sometimes underestimate how trivial it is for the average user to solve A and B. I have a lot of success just asking people if they already saw a related question, and it feels so much better to show it to them without firstly prejudging their situation by voting-to-close. Also: any thoughts on my section "Not complete"?

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*the trouble is, SO is not generally for experts.*" Don't mistake the "reasonable user" for an "expert". "*any thoughts on my section "Not complete"?*" If you close a specific question as a duplicate of a general question, then *any* user, reasonable or no, will have the answer, because the general question applies to their specific case.

Comment: @fbueckert, the site is for the user majority. I really think you would be surprised. If the power to close was handed to askers, just as they already have the privilege to choose the best answers- which I can see they mostly do correctly- the rest of us could focus our time instead on answering and editing and improving. Fewer discussions in here, less reading about how unwelcoming SO is, no more daily Metas on "why was my question closed"- less distraction all round. And, it could be setup such that questions can still be closed anyway after a few days of inactivity.

Comment: @NicolBolas, what about when the popular, frequently-asked question, is one of the limiting cases, and the general case is something people almost never care about? That's true of the example I've given. Are we really meeting SO's goals if 90% of people go to Google and say, "how do I escape the forward slash", only to find themselves at a treatise on safely and securely passing data to sed?

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*If the power to close was handed to askers*" ... what would that even mean? There's no reason, let alone incentive, for anyone who asks any question regardless of quality to close their own question. You're basically saying that we should abandon all standards and turn SO into a help desk.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*what about when the popular, frequently-asked question, is one of the limiting cases, and the general case is something people almost never care about?*" What matters is that a user searching for a problem gets the solution they need. Who cares about which is more "popular"; if they get the answer, then they get the answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas, hmm. You might be right as far as other close reasons are concerned. I guess I'm thinking only of duplicates.

Comment: @NicolBolas, the trouble is they don't get the answer they _want_. And thus, they go on looking, and they are encouraged to then ask a dupe. Again and again. And that seems to weigh against the site's goals, and leads to lower quality.

Comment: Askers *already* have the power to close; once they hit 500 rep for their own, or 3000 for others.  The problem isn't that they *can't* do it; the problem is that they **won't**; their motivations run counter to what the site is meant for.  I challenge any assertion that says we'd have less headache.  We'd have *far* more, as now we have to deal with users abusing systems, either deliberately, or out of ignorance.

Comment: Yes, @fbueckert, I accept that they are unlikely to close their questions for reasons other than dupes. And in the case of dupes, the site software could help, by asking them: looks like you might have asked a dupe there. Would you like to close this question instead with a helpful link to the dupe? I think that would work.

Comment: It already does that.  It literally asks the asker if the proposed dupe answers their question.

Comment: I'm thinking this would be smarter, because the software could note that someone proposed a specific dupe in the comments.

Comment: That's...literally what it does.  If someone proposes a dupe, the asker sees another little box under their question asking if that solves their problem, with a Yes or No.  A Yes auto-closes their question, while a No encourages them to edit it to show how it's not.

Comment: Oh...Ok, I didn't realise that. It's possible it could be less confrontational perhaps, removed from a contest of others voting-to-close against you. I simply note again that outside of SO, people who raise tickets etc generally don't fight to not have their questions closed- unless they still need help.

Comment: Well, we're not a help desk.  We've never *been* a help desk.  Lots of people treating us as one doesn't make us one.  Most of the frustration we see is from people using us as one, and running into the bits where we certainly are not, and it jars them.  SE could do a better job of setting expectations for that, but any additional barriers are curiously hard to implement.

Comment: @fbueckert We are a helpdesk. That is exactly what we are. Because that's what 99% of users think we are. They come here to get help, not to build some encyclopedia for hypothetical future googlers. The total disconnect between the expectations of those asking the questions and some of those answering them is what is leading to all this.

Comment: Yes, I also agree @MatthewTaylor. I have nothing against the goal of building a high quality Q&A database, but that database needs to be a product that emerges as a natural result of people coming here and asking for and receiving help. And, frankly, considering Google's algorithms, users ability to upvote high quality questions and answers, that's exactly what would happen if we all just...left it alone and just answered people's questions.

Comment: Again. Common sense. Hence the downvotes. In my experience questions get closed as supposed duplicates when whilst they might be to an expert, to a beginner that absolutely are not. And that's it. Case closed. This "edit the question and we'll re-open it" is complete nonsense. How often does that happen? So, as regards to the "Complete" section: I think this just reinforces the point that many supposed duplicates are not and the mindset that there is a 1-1 correspondence between questions and answers is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Nope.  You're both missing the point, and that's why you're having such a rough reception.  The repository comes *first*.  We help people as a side effect.  The fact that the vast majority of users treat us as one *does not make us one*.  SE sucks at the messaging, but at absolutely *no* point, do we ever say we are one.  But I won't ever convince either of you of that, so that's the end of this argument.

Comment: @fbueckert, it’s not really an argument that you’re making, rather a statement of what you and the majority here in Meta wants. You also seem to commit the Is/Ought Fallacy. The kinds of perfect questions you’d like to see as the norm are rarely asked ever. Rather, people do come here every day and ask for help. The Meta people may resent this but it is what it is. Which is, in practice, much closer to a help desk.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: Yes, it's not an argument; it's a declaration of principles. These are the principles under which the site was founded. These are the principles that created most of our close reasons (why else bother closing questions lacking MCVEs when guessing would "help the OP"?). These are the principles that have always been with us. You may resent this, but it is what it is. And if SO does not work in practice as its principles dictate, then we should fix SO, not our principles.

Comment: Well ok, @NicolBolas, but the principles are not like the Ten Commandments, handed down from God. The principles were one person's idea for a Q&A site and a financially viable company. They are a theory about how to build a Q&A site, and the site has been enormously successful, despite very little adherence to the principles. Considering the vast majority of people, from askers, to readers in the archives, to I'd say most people answering too, want more flexibility, at what point would you say that these principles aren't ideal and perhaps need to adapt?

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*despite very little adherence to the principles.*" I *strongly* disagree with that assessment of this site. "*at what point would you say that these principles aren't ideal and perhaps need to adapt?*" Um, never. These principles are why the site works, why the site attracted followings by *experts*. Explicitly abandoning these principles is a signal that SO *does not care about quality*, it only cares about being a help desk. And thus is no different from any forum software out there. Take away the things that make SO what it is, and it's just another Reddit.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I'm not proposing a general abandonment of principles in favour of anything goes, and no one else is either. Obviously, the site has done things right. Pragmatism over purism. Closing questions is causing conflict, and causing SO to be experienced negatively. It is clear that close voters can't close questions fast enough to stop most posts receiving answers anyway. So, we know that there is no actual harm in allowing answers, and questions could still be closed later anyway. We just want to remove the judgemental slap in the face to people seeking help that achieve nothing.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "I'm not proposing a general abandonment of principles in favour of anything goes, and no one else is either.*" Yet that is exactly what you are arguing for. Closing questions is one of the main ways of implementing our principles. By not even *trying* to close them before answers slip in, you're making a declaration that we don't have principles; we allow anything. You then unilaterally declare that no harm comes from answering bad questions (there is harm; it's why we get more bad questions) as a justification for removing the very idea of "bad questions" from the site.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: I don't see a way of reading your suggestion as anything *other* than "Post whatever you like." And I don't see any way of interpreting that stance as anything other than a complete abandonment of our "Optimize for pearls, not sand" philosophy.

Comment: @NicolBolas, believe it or not, there is a middle ground between SO's unwelcoming, close-vote, down-vote culture, and anything goes. I know, because I used to answer questions at ask.puppet.com, a Q&A site like this where we had only upvotes, no close votes and no duplicates. It worked fine, and the quality there was no worse than many of the queues here. The site is closed now, but not because it became like Reddit, but because Puppet itself became less popular and the demand wasn't there. The empirical evidence for your position isn't there. It's unfalsifiable.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: If there's no way to shut down bad content or even state what is bad and what is not, then there are no rules, nothing which can be enforced by the community. There are no community standards, no definition of what good content is, no expectation that users should produce good content. That's the very definition of "anything goes". You repeatedly say "I don't want X" but everything you then say you want ***is X***.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*Puppet itself became less popular and the demand wasn't there*" Ever ask yourself why this is the case? Why it "became less popular"? If it was so superior to SE, why did it lose out to SE? Demand wasn't there because people stopped using it. Was it because there weren't good questions to answer, because they kept getting the same question over and over? Did they burn out the regulars like every other forum out there? What caused it to fail?

Comment: @NicolBolas, you are misunderstanding my meaning. In 2013, Puppet was a trending, popular, hot technology. By 2019, Docker and Containerisation had taken over the world. Puppet is now considered by many to be legacy, and the people using it aren't as smart as they used to be. Puppet (the company) meanwhile decided to direct people to a Slack Channel for help instead. The Q&A site, as anyone can see- it's archived- is of a similar quality to SO.

Comment: @NicolBolas, _If there's no way to shut down bad content or even state what is bad and what is not_. Of course there's a way to say what is bad and what is not. You inform the asker of a bad question that their question is bad. Ask them to clarify it. After all, no one wants to answer a bad question. Or, the question goes unanswered. No answer= feedback that you asked a bad question.

Comment: That's a common argument, @Alex; "No feedback means a bad question.  No need to downvote or close it."  That throws all ability to curate right out the window, and gives zero way to differentiate a new post with no score versus a years old post with no score.  It allows you to see how well received a post is, without having any ability to denote what might be wrong with it.  Positivity alone does nothing to help others, posts, or users, improve a post.  All it does is convince them to abandon it.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*The Q&A site, as anyone can see- it's archived- is of a similar quality to SO.*" I'll assume this is true. However, it is easy to maintain quality in a small community (however "trending" you think it is, it is *nothing* compared to SO in size, or even some of our SE sites). It is much harder at the sale SO operates at. Your "no feedback = bad" thing only works at small scales, as does your "inform the asker of a bad question" idea. It does not work when you have dozens of bad questions being asked every hour.

Comment: @NicolBolas Not to mention users bent on getting an answer at all costs; the whole reason limiters and question bans were implemented.  There's a whole host of processes created specifically to limit the amount of junk the site gets.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: "*After all, no one wants to answer a bad question.*" That is patently untrue, as evidence by literally every site out there. Even SO; people are *frothing* at the mouth to answer bad questions. The problem is that your definition of "bad question" is not what SO considers a "bad question". To you, a question is not bad if it is at all possible to post *something* that theoretically could be considered an answer, or if you could maybe engage in some dialog to clear it up.

Answer (score -16):

The vast majority of users come here to get help, not to build an encyclopedia for hypothetical future googlers. Even though such an encyclopedia is much better than the forum approach (I appreciate that and have benefited myself), we mustn't lose sight of the fact that people come here for help. In my experience, supposed duplicates almost never are. They might be to an expert, they are not to a beginner. (eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153206/spring-social-authorizationexception-with-facebook). Needless to say, @CBroe didn't reply to my comment. ).

So, how about first answering the user's question and and linking to the duplicate (with an explanation of why it is a duplicate). Then later, after the user has been helped, closing the question (eg once they've accepted an answer or after a certain time).

Comment: I have participated in a number of programming help communities of the last 20 years. Every one of them cared about helping askers as their primary goal. All of them burned their answerers in just a couple of month because of the influx of low quality questions where you had to explain the same beginner concept twice a day. None of them worked for more than a couple of years until they vanished. It has a reason why SO attracts such high-quality answers an domain experts. If we want to do something, then we should try to prevent people from asking questions that can be googled in first place.

Comment: About your example: The facebook API changed. You didn't adapt your code to that change (or didn't update the library you used to query the API). New API + Old code -> problem.

Comment: @BDL But I'm not expert enough to have understood it. Just pointing to a duplicate didn't say any of what you've just said. The answer just seemed completely random (I have a specific error - here's some information about upgrading a piece of software I've never heard of). In fact, after spending a considerable amount of time finding out the answer myself, [I posted this question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253914/spring-social-authorisation-exception-with-facebook). And there's the nub of it. My answer is a an answer to my question; the supposed duplicate is not.

Comment: @BDL, I'm not a Facebook developer, and I can say that I would have absolutely no idea how those 2 questions are even related, much less dupes. I guess I should become an expert Facebook developer before asking any questions about it on SO.

Comment: @AlexHarvey: I'm not a facebook developer either. But that's the same game for every API. If I have a problem with something that stops working from one day to another and then someone tells me: Hey, the API has changed, then it's a very good reason to check if my code is compatible with those changes.

Comment: @BDL But I'm not even a developer (I'm a hardware engineer). So, I didn't know even that.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor: "*The vast majority of users come here to get help, not to build an encyclopedia for hypothetical future googlers.*" That is very true, and the secret behind SO. But we must not lose site of the fact that the *reason SO exists* is to build that "encyclopedia for hypothetical future googlers"; helping the asker must *never* override the core goal. SO works at its best when helping the asker aligns with that encyclopedia thing. But when they diverge, we must always prioritize the latter. That is basically why most close reasons exist.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor: "*But I'm not even a developer (I'm a hardware engineer). So, I didn't know even that.*" Then it would be fair to say that you are not a "Reasonable User" for Stack Overflow. That is, it is reasonable for a site for programmers to expect its audience... to be programmers.

Comment: @NicolBolas As someone who is "not a developer" I don't have to expertise to link my "why do I get this error message" question to the "this is how you upgrade some random piece of software answer". But as someone who is "not a developer", I still need help, because I have a website to maintain. There is a whole nother dimension  here - how expert is the asker. But that is usually fairly clear from the question. If you just answer the question, less assumptions need to be need. If you just link to some other vague answer, then an assumption about the expertise has been made...

Comment: @NicolBolas ... Basically, if I ask "why do I get a horrible grinding noise when I push the break pedal", the answer is "probably because your brake pads are worn", not "here's how to change the brake pads on a VW Golf mk5".

Comment: @MatthewTaylor: As previously stated, we are not here to "just answer the question". We are here to build a searchable database of problems and solutions. If answering your question does not help us build that, then "just answering the question" is counter-productive to our ends.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor: If you have a problem, and someone suggests that you do a thing, why is it unreasonable to assume that they are implying that the thing they're suggesting is the solution to your problem? If you honestly need someone to guide you from "squealing noise" to "here's how to change your break pads" with "your break pads need to be changed,"... why?

Comment: It's been made clear that there *is* a [barrier to entry](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378753/spooked-by-robotic-repetitive-questions-in-the-first-post-review/378769#comment661548_378769) here, @Matthew.  There is a minimum bar that has to be met in order to participate here.  One of those is going to be at least a modicum of knowledge in the problem space you're encountering.  I don't think it's unreasonable to have to meet that expectation.

Comment: @NicolBolas because you are assuming the wrong level of expertise. The brake pads example is perhaps too simple. The fact is that I, who is very far from being stupid, who teaches OO design, who has a website with 120k users to maintain, was not helped at all by the link to the supposed duplicate. And that is for a very simple reason: the duplicate answer was not an answer to the question. And, irony of ironies: I was that hypothetical future googler that this site is supposedly all about helping.