# What to do when someone starts a "close as duplicate" on a canonical Q&A?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, dupehammer, canonical

I'm a bit annoyed by this.  Someone has decided to start a vote-to-close as duplicate on a canonical Q&A that I created:

[What does "possible lossy conversion" mean and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632152/what-does-possible-lossy-conversion-mean-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Not only that, but they appear to have chosen a rather "mediocre" question as the dup target ... as indicated by the respective votes.

As someone with a gold badge for Java questions, I could reopen the question if it closes.  But I can't do that until it closes.  I could also dup-close it myself and then immediately reopen it, but that is liable to create a storm, and accusations of "abuse".

What should I do?

Is this something that moderators would intervene in?

Comment: Why should a "canonical Q&A" have some magic protection against closure? It is possible to discuss if the chosen target is worth it or not, but getting annoyed because it got a close vote? Come on.

Comment: What would you for example do in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568261/how-to-avoid-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-or-indexoutofboundsexception? This was an intended canonical question which duplicates an already existing canonical question.

Comment: "Why should a "canonical Q&A" have some magic protection against closure?" - Did I say that in my meta Question?

Comment: Yes you did. You first said you're annoyed because someone dared to cast a close-vote and then you criticized the quality of the chosen dupe-target.

Comment: have you considered dupe-closing in the opposite direction? this would make it impossible to close the other way 'round

Comment: Wouldn't that be abusing the dup-hammer?   Actually, nobody has actually answered that aspect of my question.  Would it be acceptable to just dup-hammer the attempted dup-close?

Comment: "just dup-hammer" wouldn't be OK, that's for sure. However, with a [canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) Q&A there is naturally a fat chance that when someone attempts to dupe it to narrower question, the closure in the opposite direction is indeed better. As a gold badge holder in relevant tag you appear to be in the best position to decide whether it is so in this specific case or not

Comment: given this pair of questions dupe close of narrower one would probably be okay if canonical would be expanded to explicitly cover case when implicit conversion happens when passing arguments and pointing to alternative solutions, one of changing the type of method arguments (when coder can control that) and another of casting

Answer (score 8):

It was a valid duplicate suggestion.

However, the question that you created as a canonical is a better question with a better answer, and it is long-standing convention that the *best* question be kept as the “main” question. Duplicate closure need not take the age of the question into account.

Therefore, I have closed the suggested question as a duplicate of your canonical.

This action was suggested in the comments, and you replied that you were reluctant to use your gold badge to do so, as it might be a conflict of interest. That is a valid concern; you taking this action may certainly have been perceived this way. In this particular case, I would have supported and defended the decision, but in the general case, it is probably best to leave the decision to a third party.

I have also removed the meta-commentary that you edited into the question. That does not belong. If the question can’t stand on its own merits, then it is not a valid question for this site. Your intention in creating it (e.g., to serve as a canonical) is not relevant.

Comment: "it is long-standing convention that the best question be kept as the “main” question"  This may be true among moderators,  but those of us lowlings, voting in the close queues, have no "real" say in the matter, if it smells like a duck... (groupthink at its best.) My vote to keep it open is wrong according to the system; Since I chose the best question to remain open. This is an almost completely hypothetical scenario, since I tend to skip duplicate closures, unless I know enough about both questions and their answers to make an informed judgement, but way too many reviewers follow the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for the close vote to expire. It's a single user and a single vote.

If the question actually got closed, then we'd have to discuss if that's appropriate and if you should reopen yourself. But since it's only one vote, we can ignore it, and hope the vote expires, which probably will happen (most votes on old questions expire since the queue is not really functional, unless backed by a chat room or meta).

After the vote expired, you can decide to flag the comment as no longer needed if you feel the need to.

Comment: To play devil's advocate... *"hope the vote expires"*. Why would you hope that? Why shouldn't we close duplicates?

Comment: I assume the OP here is knowledgeable and the vote is truly inappropriate (since he has a gold badge on the subject, and can unilaterally make decisions on duplicate votes). If that assumption is wrong, then we should of course hope it gets closed, though as said, the odds are slim since it's an old question. The fact that it got raised on meta might shift the odds a bit in favor of closing, though. But I don't have a strong opinion either way myself.

Answer (score -2):

Since the question you asked is in fact a duplicate of the question it is proposed as a duplicate as, you should confirm the closure of the question, and not vote to reopen a question that is in fact a duplicate.

That you "wanted to create a canonical" doesn't make your question not a duplicate.  That your question was duplicating an already answered question when you posted it means it *wasn't* the canonical version of that question when you posted it, regardless of your meta commentary in the question attempting to state otherwise.

If you feel that your answer is better than the answer on the original, feel free to post your answer on the original question instead of the duplicate.

Comment: This answer is basically saying that creating deliberate canonical questions isn't possible, that all canonical questions are (or should be) *promoted* rather than *created*. To me, the point of a canonical question is that it *canonizes* the duplicates. That various duplicates may have lots of extraneous filler information, but the canonical one cuts all that out and gets right to the heart of the matter. That's why using it as the dupe target, even for older questions, is better: it makes the point absolutely clear with no extraneous stuff. Which is what this canonical does.

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course you can create deliberate canonical questions.  It just needs to be of a question *that hasn't already been asked and answered*.  If there is an existing question for which you feel there is lots of extraneous filler information then *edit that information out*.  That's why we let people edit posts.  removing extraneous information is one of the primary purposes of it, rather than forcing people to re-ask a question just to have an altered version of *the same fundamental question*.

Comment: "*It just needs to be of a question that hasn't already been asked and answered.*" But nobody creates canonicals for things nobody has asked about. You create canonicals to close other things as dupe-targets. The existence of those "other things" is what *makes you* need a canonical Q&A.

Comment: "*If there is an existing question for which you feel there is lots of extraneous filler information then edit that information out.*" You can't do that, because that would be changing the intent of the question, which we are explicitly not allowed to do. If someone asks about cube rendering, that's what they're asking about: rendering a cube. It doesn't matter that the problem with cube rendering is multi-index rendering; the goal of that question was *rendering a cube*.

Comment: @NicolBolas People ask non-duplicate questions all the time.  Not all of the questions asked on this site are in fact duplicate, even if there are quite a few.  If there are lots of duplicates of a question then we don't need *more duplicates*, we just need to close the duplicates that already exist, and improve the existing canonical if needed.

Comment: @NicolBolas If editing the information out would be changing what the question is asking then *that information wasn't extraneous*.  Extraneous information is, *by definition*, information which does not change what the question is asking, and can be removed without changing what is being asked.

Comment: Remember the ["Reasonable User" theory of duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384711/the-reasonable-user-theory-of-duplicate-questions)
. The canonical is a question *explicitly and directly* about Q. That's the point of it. Problems A and B are not extraneous to the question; they are only extraneous to the *duplicate*.

Comment: @NicolBolas This isn't a case where the duplicate target asks about an entirely different issue whose root cause happened to be the same as what this user was asking about.  They really are asking *exactly the same question*.  Both questions are just a copy paste of an error message and a "what does this even mean?" question and some code that reproduces it that doesn't actually matter.  Except that one has some irrelevant meta commentary about the fact that it's trying to be a canonical.

Comment: OK, let's follow that line of reasoning. By that definition, the older question has a lot of extraneous information; namely, the huge code listing. So we should just delete that. But then, the question lacks an MCVE, and therefore should be closed. Whereas the newer question makes it clear that it doesn't need an MCVE because it's asking about the subject in a general way that isn't about any one specific example.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, if you deleted the *entire* code snippet it would lack an MCVE, however if you removed the parts of the code snippet that are irrelevant (which is most of it), you'd turn it *into* an MCVE.  Both questions are asking the same thing.  Both benefit from having an MCVE (which neither technically has, one's not complete, one's not minimal).  It makes no sense to say one needs it and one doesn't when *they're asking the same thing*.

Comment: But that's my point: they're *not* asking the same thing. The older one is asking "why doesn't this code compile, seemingly due to this line?" The newer one is asking "what does this error message, produced by code of this form, mean, and what do I do about it?" One is asking about a specific case; the other is explicitly very general. The latter doesn't need an MCVE because it's not asking about debugging; it's asking about the meaning of an error.

Comment: @NicolBolas But it's *not* asking that.  Both questions ask why the code produces the error, and both ask how to fix it.  Both questions provide a specific case they're asking about, and both questions ask for a solution that applies to the general case.  The only difference between them is that one was asked because they actually faced the problem, and one know the question was a duplicate when they posted it.

Comment: @NicolBolas If there were a hypothetical case where there was an existing question that was more specific, and a newer question that asked a broader version on the same topic, then either the broader question would be Too Broad, or it would not be a duplicate of the older question, and wouldn't merit closure (unless there was some other existing answered question that covered the same scope).  That's just not this pair of questions as neither is broader in scope than the other.

Comment: I guess the problem I have with your definition is that it doesn't fit our established standards for [how canonical Q&As work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/734069). By your reasoning, the NullReference Exception question shouldn't have been asked and should have been closed as a duplicate of one of the older questions (it was created in response to the multitude of such questions, after all). You may argue that this *specific case* is not really a canonical question, but your larger point seems to argue against the practice of *writing* canonical Q&As entirely.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, there was no reason for that question to actually have been asked in the first place.  An existing question could have been used as the target of duplicates on null references exceptions with a good answer and perhaps a bit of editing.  Obviously at this point it is the canonical version of that question; there's no changing that at this point, but there was no need to make *another duplicate* when it was first asked to have a duplicate target for null reference exceptions. Making *another duplicate* didn't help it at all.

Comment: Why do so many people think a question needs to have been knowingly asked as a duplicate, and typically written poorly, in order for it to be the target of duplicate closures?  It's just *not useful* when you can take an *existing* good question on the topic and, if needed (for a frequently asked topic, there is likely already a quality question), improve it.  Also I don't have a problem with writing canonical questions, i have a problem with asking *duplicate* questions.  Write a canonical of a question that  *hasn't been asked*, otherwise improve the existing canonical.

Comment: "*Why do so many people think a question needs to have been knowingly asked as a duplicate, and typically written poorly, in order for it to be the target of duplicate closures?*" That's a "when did you stop beating your wife" kind of question. We *do not agree* that canonicals are "typically poorly written". As for the purpose of them, they make the *actual* problem clear. Like I mentioned, a good canonical is about problem Q, the core of the user's issue, not any hypothetical problems P that they think they're having. That's what makes them better dupe targets.

Comment: "*Write a canonical of a question that hasn't been asked*" How can you write a "canonical" of a question that hasn't been asked, when *by definition*, "canonical questions" are written *in response to* questions that have been asked? Or more to the point, show me a canonical Q&A, one that was specifically written to be canonical, that was written ex-nihilo, without any prior history of questions on the same subject.

Comment: @NicolBolas Show me a single question that you think is a good canonical that would be a good question if the author didn't also post an answer along with the question.  People are bad at writing self answered questions *in general* (because it's hard), when they're intentionally trying to make something a duplicate of as many questions as they can, it only makes asking a question actually meeting the site's quality standards all that much harder.  And of course the worst part is that there's just *no need* in most cases.

Comment: @NicolBolas A canonical question is *not*, by definition, in response to questions that have been asked.  A canonical question is the official or primary version of that question.  Every question that is the first non-duplicate quality question of the problem it is asking about is (or should be) the canonical version of that question.  You don't need to ask *another duplicate* because a type of question is being asked a lot.  You just need to have a good general answer and *actually vote to close questions*.  It's the good answer, that's important, not the asking another duplicate.

Comment: "*You just need to have a good general answer*" That's where we disagree. What you need is a good, general ***question***, because the question is what people following the dupe link will see first. The question needs to jump directly to Q without any extraneous A or B issues. And most users *do not ask about Q*, nor is it allowed to remove A or B issues from their questions about P because it changes the intent of their question. That's why we need to write questions explicitly intended to be canonical questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas When a question is really asked that much it's pretty rare for there to not be a suitably general question out there, as is of course the case here, *the duplicate question was asking exactly the same question, with the same level of generality*.  Usually when people are trying to forcibly make their own canonical they tend to make the question *too* broad.  The questions asked by someone actually trying to understand the problem that get a good answer tend to make better canonical questions because they don't overreach and try to cover more than can actually be answered.

Comment: I can only speak to my experience. But when I dupe-hammer questions as duplicates of *my* explicitly-written-to-be canonicals, nobody has ever said "this isn't a duplicate of that!". But that happens when using ad-hoc canonical duplicates. So from my experience, linking people directly to Q is generally more effective at getting them in the right headspace than linking them to a different problem P2 that happens to have the same Q, which gets explained in the answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see people complaining about duplicate closures of self answered questions all the time.  Also when you create questions trying to cover an entire book chapter in them, people will complain about their answer being somewhere in paragraph 26 of an answer otherwise irrelevant to them.  But it sounds like you could be improving the questions you're using as canonicals some, to mitigate your problem.  Often in my experience the problem is the question title not accurately describing what the question body is covering, so improving the titles often goes a long way.

Comment: This may be applicable to the situation in general: [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740) But the caution is, the question was not turned over to the community, so a discussion of community wiki may not apply. (I can't really tell the difference is in application between a community wiki and a canonical answer. Does anyone know when to prefer one to the other?)

Comment: @jww CW would be applicable when the answer is a collaborative work of multiple people (often, but not necessarily, coordinated outside of that post, i.e. in chat, a meta discussion on the topic, or outside the site entirely).  Coordination of many people to write an answer is often overkill on an answer that's not a canonical answer (so people don't do it as often on posts with a really narrow scope), but not all canonical answers are in fact collaborative works of multiple people, so there's a correlation there.