# Should you edit or vote to close questions with multiple questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-close

In the comments on the answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386139/4032703), there was a discussion about how to handle cases where someone asks multiple questions at once. I had always assumed that you should vote to close in these cases; however, in the comments it was suggested that we should edit instead. Specifically, we should edit out all but one question and then comment telling the OP to create new questions for the other questions.

What’s the proper way to handle these questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the asker is amenable to the edit, great. Problem is, many times they won't be.

Any time a question is was closable, but you can edit into shape without invalidating answers, awesome.

If the question was closable maybe it shouldn't have been answered in the first place, but there are corner cases with useful answers provided for subpar questions, and you wouldn't want your edit to make those answers to look silly because you removed the question they were answering.

But if the asker doesn't agree with the edits... well, not much else to do but vote to close.

Comment: So basically we should try to edit/comment first, but if the OP refuses to  go along with it just vote to close until such time as they agree to follow the site rules?

Comment: Which questions to delete while editing? Keep the most significant or the first or the best understandable question?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'd say edit first if you can see a clear path to question redemption (and you are willing, and have the time). Otherwise, just vote to close. Comment if you want, but voting to close is enough. The onus on asking a good question is still with the asker.

Comment: @stats0007 If I were salvaging a multi-question like this, I'd do it because I feel I'm an expert in the involved technology, and likely I'm willing to post an answer (or maybe there are already one or more answers focusing in the most appropriate question). So choosing should be more or less straightforward. If it isn't, I guess we won't be saving the question after all.