# Is it time to reward OPs for accepting a proposed duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

OK, so the title may seem daft, and even a wee bit provocative but, I prithee, let me explain! First, [some context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394048/10871073): duplicate questions are a source of great consternation among the Stack Overflow community; here, I'm proposing a slightly different approach to help in tackling the problem.

New users are often bewildered by the search engine offered by the site, and they shouldn't always be blamed or punished for asking a duplicate question - so long as it is otherwise well presented. Indeed, even with a thorough search, a relative beginner in a particular programming language may not even know that their question is the same as another, if the title isn't helpful to them. Only after having the duplicate pointed out do they realize the answer to *their* question is already on S.O.

The main problem comes (at least, in my humble opinion) when those questions are *answered*.

When the first "Duplicate" vote is made, they are presented with a friendly blue box that links the proposed duplicate and asks them if it answers their question.

I am suggesting that, if they 'accept' that duplicate, then they should be given the same +2 reputation they would get if they were to later formally "Accept" an answer that was posted (that option would, of course, then be disabled). Further, if they have *already* accepted an answer before they first see the Beautiful Blue Box, their Accept 'vote' would be withdrawn (along with the reputation granted to the poster of the answer) - but they would keep their +2. Also, it may be helpful if the text of the "Blue Box" told them about the reputation gain.

This would possibly discourage folks from answering duplicates (currently, it take 8 downvotes to wipe out the +15 from an accepted answer) *without* adversely affecting new, innocent users.

But I *can* see that there is potential scope for 'abuse' here, and that any such feature would need to be very carefully engineered. For example, the +2 rep. wouldn't be offered to the same user for the same duplicate target. It may also be prudent to limit this 'benefit', either to new users, or to those below a certain reputation level.

Just for clarity, and following some of the comments: The *primary* reason I am suggesting this feature is to speed up the process of closing duplicates; and, thus, to reduce the number of *answered* duplicates. The "Mjölnir" argument is something of a red herring: Gold Tag-Badge holders can close quickly (on sight); the idea here is to try to reduce the time taken for 'ordinary' close votes to become effective. I don't have any statistics to hand, but, from experience, the "Community ♦" closer doesn't seem to appear that often.

I'm fairly sure this post doesn't qualify for [Yaakov's competition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349555/616624); nevertheless, just for the fun of it:

> I asked a question on the Stack,
> That had been answered, way, way back.
> I didn't know that that was true,
> Until I saw the Box-in-Blue.
> That little pop-up, so polite,
> Truly was my Guiding Light.

Comment: I think a badge would be more appropriate, since the gamification here is weird (you need to be in time to accept, if it gets dupehammered you can't), there's no need for a returning reward (as one should learn the lesson and not post multiple duplicates), and earning rep by posting duplicates is somewhat counterproductive because duplicates should get deleted if they're not great signposts, which would then revert the rep change (badges are sometimes not reverted, rep always is).

Comment: @ErikA Yeah - A badge would also be good. My aim is not primarily to *reward* the asker as such (despite the title); rather it is to *not punish* them.

Comment: I don't know... If the post is good, the ones that help linking it to the dupes should upvote it. End of story. I know it's not done often, I suspect some even downvote questions as soon as they see the duplicate banner, without any effort to actually check the quality of the post, but rewarding the asker directly doesn't seem like the best way to fix that issue. IMO, askers aren't really the ones that need to change their behavior here as much as are the ones that don't vote accordingly to posts quality. I'd rather see some badge or "reward" when their post was used as sign-post.

Comment: @ErikA At the risk of invoking the terrible wrath of the "Meta Effect" ... this did happen to me, in one of my [very early questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57660047/10871073). At the time, there was absolutely *no way* I would ever have found any of the duplicates without knowing it was called "Most Vexing Parse." That post had no answer (well, one that was quickly deleted by its poster) and was closed with a Mjölnir.

Comment: @Kaiido But there's nothing in my proposal that would prevent upvotes on a good post, even after it's closed as a dupe. And there's nothing wrong with that, either. As you say, such posts can be good signposts.

Comment: @ErikA If it's dupe-hammered, then obviously this will make it a no-reputation gain for the poster, same as before. But.. the poster gets their +2 reputation point when they accepted an answer on their post. So this has the side-effect of discouraging answering the duplicate with low gamification options for the poster. (If they can post - accept answer, they can also post - accept target. So again, same as before)

Comment: I think I remember some off-hand mention about making dupes into answers. As in, a dupe link is turned into an answer where you can add a bit more content, if needed (I usually do it as a comment anyway). And then that answer can be accepted as normal which confirms the dupe link.

Comment: @AdrianMole from my point of view, your proposal is not aiming at the correct target. If what you want is to teach that posting good sign-post is good for the community, and encouraged, a mere +2 when accepting a dupe doesn't sound like a great improvement. I personally think the vote system is once again the best tool for this, and that the root issue is more in the reaction of the community regarding dupes. i.e we should rather find a tool to teach the other users to vote on content quality. So yes, your proposal doesn't remove the ability to vote, but I'm not sure it adds anything.

Comment: But I also agree that something could be done in this area, and maybe if we want to reward the good duplicate askers, then they should get a reward when their post was used as a sing-post (i.e when someone gets redirected to the dupe from their post). Because the biggest issue when your question gets closed as dupe is that most users won't even see your post since they'll get redirected directly.

Comment: OK I think [I found it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384812/) - it's a post by Jon Ericson

Comment: @Kaiido Redirected how exactly? I land on dupes quite often enough to be honest. It mostly depends on if that dupe has answers or not, since Google generally links me to answers and not directly to a question.

Comment: @Gimby I don't remember exactly if low reps are also concerned, but at least anonymous users (a.k.a the vast majority of SO visitors) can't see a question closed as dupe, they are automagically redirected to the first post in the list of dupes.

Comment: On the Gold-Hammer issue: If the closer considers that, despite being a dupe, it is an otherwise well-presented question, then we should encourage those 'experts' to upvote the question; or, at the very least, to leave a comment with a brief explanation and/or some other welcoming/consoling message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It's time to reward the duplicate finders](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394048/its-time-to-reward-the-duplicate-finders)

Comment: ^ I think the duplicate finder should be rewarded, not the posters. If a post is well written and well searched and the duplicate isn't trivial then you can simply upvote the question

Comment: *The main problem comes (at least, in my humble opinion) when those questions are answered.* --> there is no problem in answering duplicate. The problem is answering trivial/well known/nth duplicate question. Having 10 or even 20 question dealing with the same issue in the site isn't an issue but having 1000 similar questions is an issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not a duplicate :) It's not even a reward to the poster, that's any different than the reward they're already getting.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't think its a duplicate. But thanks for suggesting it: I hadn't actually *seen* that Beautiful Blue Box for quite a while!

Comment: @Scratte I think it's a duplicate because it deals with rewards around duplicates. This idea can belong there to say why we need to rewards posters and not only finders.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It would be terribly confusing to write an answer on the other post for this post. Which would be the only way if this is closed. An answer to the other post should address the other Question, not this one.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? PS Whatever else, remove rep from asking and answering.

Answer (score 21):

My impression so far is that it's time to **reward and encourage duplication linking in general**. Most tags are saturated with questions around the same root problem. As the flood of questions asked isn't going away any time soon, we need to build the bridge from both ends:

- Educate users against the non-scalable approach of posting answers to the same problem;
- Let askers embrace the concept of duplicate as their own problem solving tool.

As a personal example, in [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust), an increasing yet low traffic tag, I voted to close as a duplicate at least 13 questions, almost half of which were accepted by the OP. In contrast, I only posted 4 answers in the same tag in the same time window. Three of these duplicates were in a single day (I cannot claim to be following the tag every single one of these days). None of these duplicates have incurred a reward for me finding them. The total number of questions asked and still visible with the tag in the same range is around 150, which is still somewhat bearable, but in high traffic tags, the task of finding duplicates feels Herculean. My point is that this encouragement makes sense even for lower traffic tags.

This, of course, does not excuse the powers that be to [improve the platform's search capabilities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387265). However, anything that can be done to encourage "web building" among the sea of questions is a plus.